# What are Bitcoin Lightning Watchtowers exactly doing for the network and users?

Tags: lightning-network, watchtower

I'm still learning about Bitcoin lightning and learned about watchtowers. What are they doing exactly for the network and its users?

Answer (score 4):

Watchtowers are monitoring for attempted Lightning channel closes using revoked states and when they identify one they can broadcast the justice transaction claiming **all** (eltoo may change this in future but that is not possible under current consensus rules) the funds in the channel for the "cheated" party. This attempted closing of a channel using a revoked state may be done accidentally or maliciously. The security assumption for Lightning relies on being online 24/7 (or close to it) so that you can respond to an attempted channel close with a revoked state with your own justice transaction in a timely manner. With a watchtower (or multiple watchtowers in place) a party in a Lightning channel no longer has to be online 24/7 as they can rely on the watchtower to monitor the chain and respond if required.

Comment: What if the watchtower goes offline for that duration?

Comment: Of course, you're not protected if both you and your watchtower go offline for a significant period. Like with an insurance policy, if your insurer goes bankrupt you aren't covered. A watchtower's primary job is to stay online. You could have multiple watchtowers which reduces the probability of them all going offline at the same time though.